# hidden newline in long cell entries

Tags: cells

I need to store long strings from mathematica to a text file.

Unfortunately, mathematica provides long cell entries (input/output) after approx the 70th position with a hidden backslash and a new line character:

> / NL

or hex:

> 5C 0A

For example, when you write or copy/paste long strings into a text file, the backslash and the newline become visible:

```
Put[" This ---------------- is ---------------- a ---------------- long ---------------- line", "text.txt"]
```

The content of text.txt is now 2 separate lines and the backslash is visible:

> " This ---------------- is ---------------- a ---------------- long \
> ---------------- line"

Can this behavior be prevented?

I've tried a lot with:

> Text[...], ToString[...], CharacterEncoding -> "...."

I work with Linux and mathematica V13

regards
2stein

Comment: I am trying to understand why the cell outputs have to be copied and pasted manually to a text file. This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put and Get work with Mathematica expressions. The contents of the file generated with Put is not intended to be read/understood by other programs.

You probably want to use Export (and Import if you need to read the data back into Mathematica).

Comment: Many thanks for your important note

In my case, WriteLine[...] works fine too.